# Changing the duplicate message

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

Currently, the duplicate message looks something like this:

[image: mesage]

It says that the if the answers do not address your question you should ask a new one.

But you can edit it as well to put it in the reopen queue. Why not add that?

It could look like this:

[image: new image]

Comment: But OPs were already summoned to edit their question before it is closed as duplicate (unless it was dupe hammered).

Comment: i am flagging this as duplicate